# Reusing a stub/redef across a speclj context

Tags: clojure, bdd, speclj

I'm writing tests for a Clojure app using Speclj. I'm accustomed in BDD to do things like this:

```
context "some context"
  stub my-function :return true
  it "has behavior one"
    should true my-function
  it "has behavior two"
    should_not false my-function
```

But in Speclj I can't seem to find an example of how to share the stub across the characteristics, so I'm currently stuck writing code like this:

```
(describe "this"
  (context "that"
    (it "accepts nil"
      (with-redefs [called-fn (constantly nil)]
          (should= nil (my-fn nil)))))
    (it "accepts 1"
      (with-redefs [called-fn (constantly nil)]
          (should= 100 (my-fn 1))))))
```

(I realize this is a somewhat contrived example and arguably those assertions could all go under one characteristic, but let's suppose for now that I have good reason to write the code like this.)

I want, however, to just have to stub `called-fn` once, but moving this up out of the `it`s raises errors because the real `called-fn` gets called instead of my redef.

Is there a way to reuse redefs (or use Speclj stubs) in Speclj so I'm not stuck pushing them all down inside the characteristics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `around` macro to accomplish this.

Here's an example spec:

```
(ns sample.core-spec
  (:require [speclj.core :refer :all]
            [sample.core :refer :all]))

(describe "a test"
  (it "returns output from fn-a"
    (should= 1 (fn-b)))

  (describe "using with-redef"
    (around [it] (with-redefs [fn-a (fn [] 2)] (it)))

    (it "returns the output from redefined function"
      (should= 2 (fn-b)))))
```

Source:

```
(ns sample.core)

(defn fn-a []
  1)

(defn fn-b []
  (fn-a))
```